# How to optimize variable declaration in unit tests with jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React application with multiple components and each of those has it's own corresponding test.
The issue is that multiple tests need fake elements in the props which can get a bit messy like so:

```
const mockIStyleDetailsProps: IStyleDetailsProps = {
  currentStyleOption: {
    number: fakeStyleNumber,
    name: fakeStyleOptionName,
    color: {
      pantone: fakePantone,
      hex: fakeHex,
      basic: fakeBasic,
    } as Color,
    eaNs: fakeEANs,
    assets: [
      {
        perspective: {
          number: fakeNumber,
          name: fakePerspectiveName,
          assetType: fakeAssetType,
        } as Perspective,
        file: {
          extension: fakeExtention,
          name: fakeAssetName,
          size: fakeAssetSizeNumber,
          createdOn: Date,
          modifiedOn: Date,
          storageUrl: fakeStorageUrl,
        } as File,
        channel: fakeChannel,
      },
    ] as Asset[],
  } as StyleOption,
  styleName: fakeStyleName,
  styleOptionNumber: fakeStyleOptionNumber,
  brandName: fakeBrandName,
  description: fakeDescription
};
```

**Is there a more convenient way to declare the props above with the same attributes?**

I imagine that a the `StyleOption` can be build with some default values somehow, so that I can use it in a test like:

```
const mockIStyleDetailsProps: IStyleDetailsProps = {
  currentStyleOption: StyleOptionBuilder.build(), 
  styleName: fakeStyleName,
  styleOptionNumber: fakeStyleOptionNumber,
  brandName: fakeBrandName,
  description: fakeDescription
};
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is to create a mockCreator function that defaults to your mock but can return a modified value. Then you build your tree out of that:

```
const mockIStyleDetailsProps: IStyleDetailsProps = {
  currentStyleOption: StyleOptionBuilder.build(), 
  styleName: fakeStyleName,
  styleOptionNumber: fakeStyleOptionNumber,
  brandName: fakeBrandName,
  description: fakeDescription
};

export const IStyleDetailsPropsMockCreator = (partial: Partial<IStyleDetailsProps>) => Object.assign({}, mockIStyleDetailsProps, partial;
```

You can later use this mock creator in your other mocks:

```
import { IStyleDetailsPropsMockCreator } from './IStyleDetailsPropsMockCreator'

export const newMock: INewMock = {
  iStyleDetailsProps: IStyleDetailsPropsMockCreator({brandName: 'test'})
}

export const newMockMockCreator = (partial: Partial<INewMock>) =>
    Object.assign({}, newMock, partial)
```

And use it like this:

```
const newestMock = newMockMockCreator({
  iStyleDetailsProps: IStyleDetailsPropsMockCreator({brandName: 'someotherbrand'})
});
```

It is then a good idea to create a createMockCreator function:

```
export createMockCreator<T>(defaultState: T) => 
  (partial: Partial<T>) => Object.assign({}, defaultState, partial);
```